# dynamically add gridview on page

Tags: c#

how i can add gridview dynamically with itemTemplate to the page using c# code?
I wanted to add dynamic no of gridview (3 to 10) as per requirement on page.
i want template sort of class which will create & handle 'n' gridviews design & events

Comment: I want code like 
1.create Control as requied (checkbox,textbox) 
2. create itemTemplate, Add it using control.add() that add to gridview 
3. That gridview also to page using control.add()

Comment: Still unable to get you. If you describe your case, may I will be able to understand!

Comment: @Akram: I have requirement that no. of gridview varies as request come to page. when i want to add gridview to page,it is to be added dynamically. There will not be any HTML on aspx or cs too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn about adding controls to an *ASP.NET* page at runtime, refer to the following articles:

[How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)

[[How Do I:] Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-add-controls-to-an-aspnet-web-page-programmatically) (Video)

Comment: could i add entire gridview in <div> with design (itemTemplate) & events as i want?

Comment: @MayP: Yes. But, it wont be easy at all.

Comment: is there any code example as per my requirement.
at least steps could i get?

Comment: @MayP: It is rare to find an example on the net for specific cases. Aspecialy for such cases as yours !!